# PHP message: WordPress database error Deadlock found when trying to get lock

Tags: plugins, database

I'm trying to fix this deadlock issue on my site without luck. I'm using WordFence and when I disable it, the error is gone. I disabled the plugin by removing it completely and reinstall it again, but the error also appear whenever I reinstall it.

Note that I have uninstalled the plugin completely as suggested by WordFence.

Anyone know what's causing this?

Here's the log on my server:

```
2018/09/14 01:13:38 [error] 21753#21753: *2868716 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: WordPress database error Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction for query INSERT IGNORE INTO `pn_wfconfig` (`name`, `val`, `autoload`) VALUES ('wfSyncGeoIP.lock', '1536912818', 'no') made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('plugins_loaded'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, wordfence::veryFirstAction, wfConfig::createLock, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->query, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbInjection_QueryCaching->query, W3TC\_CallUnderlying->query, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->query, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbInjection->query, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->default_query" while reading response header from upstream, client: 34.232.72.139, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /2017/09/19/sample-article/feed/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9011", host: "mysite.com"
2018/09/14 01:13:57 [error] 21753#21753: *2869493 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: WordPress database error Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction for query INSERT IGNORE INTO `pn_wfconfig` (`name`, `val`, `autoload`) VALUES ('wfSyncGeoIP.lock', '1536912837', 'no') made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('plugins_loaded'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, wordfence::veryFirstAction, wfConfig::createLock, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->query, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbInjection_QueryCaching->query, W3TC\_CallUnderlying->query, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->query, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbInjection->query, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->default_query" while reading response header from upstream, client: 54.241.188.65, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /test-article/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9011", host: "mysite.com", referrer: "search.yahoo.com/"
2018/09/14 01:14:03 [error] 21753#21753: *2869668 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: WordPress database error Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction for query INSERT IGNORE INTO `pn_wfconfig` (`name`, `val`, `autoload`) VALUES ('wfSyncGeoIP.lock', '1536912842', 'no') made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('plugins_loaded'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, wordfence::veryFirstAction, wfConfig::createLock, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->query, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbInjection_QueryCaching->query, W3TC\_CallUnderlying->query, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->query, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbInjection->query, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->default_query" while reading response header from upstream, client: 13.56.241.76, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /2013/07/17/testing/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9011", host: "philnews.ph", referrer: "android-app://com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox"
2018/09/14 01:14:03 [error] 21753#21753: *2869683 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: WordPress database error Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction for query INSERT IGNORE INTO `pn_wfconfig` (`name`, `val`, `autoload`) VALUES ('wfSyncGeoIP.lock', '1536912843', 'no') made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('plugins_loaded'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, wordfence::veryFirstAction, wfConfig::createLock, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->query, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbInjection_QueryCaching->query, W3TC\_CallUnderlying->query, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->query, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbInjection->query, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->default_query" while reading response header from upstream, client: 54.193.113.108, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /sample/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9011", host: "mysite.com", referrer: "mysite.com/articl1/"
2018/09/14 01:15:14 [error] 21753#21753: *2871964 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: WordPress database error Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction for query INSERT IGNORE INTO `pn_wfconfig` (`name`, `val`, `autoload`) VALUES ('wfSyncGeoIP.lock', '1536912914', 'no') made by require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('plugins_loaded'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, wordfence::veryFirstAction, wfConfig::createLock, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->query, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbInjection_QueryCaching->query, W3TC\_CallUnderlying->query, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->query, W3TC\DbCache_WpdbInjection->query, W3TC\DbCache_Wpdb->default_query
```

Comment: Sounds like a question for the WordFence support channels, no?

Comment: they're not replying either.

Answer (score 0):

Is caused by a security plugin (Wordfence, WP Cerber, etc.) that has created a "must use" partial copy of itself which is running when the main plugin is disabled/missing), commonly called the "Citadel mode."  Its preventing any malicious damage to the database by locking the tables.
You have probably deleted the main plugin manually, without allowing it to remove the MU plugin.
Delete the plugin in the MU folder manually also (in the case of WP-Cerber its 'aaa-wp-cerber.php'), or, preferably, reinstall the main plugin and run the removal script normally so it will remove ALL of its tables and records.